# If i opened a visual studio project with newer visual studio version , can I open it again with the older visual studio version?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

I have a visual studio 2008 project if I open it with 2015 visual studio can I open it again with visual studio 2008?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Visual Studio 2008 Solution in Visual Studio 2013 without Upgrading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366086/open-visual-studio-2008-solution-in-visual-studio-2013-without-upgrading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the project file will be upgraded and cannot be opened with the previous version of Visual Studio.

However Visual Studio will create a backup of the old project file and other files in your project that will be modified on upgrade.

Using this backup is your only chance to open the project with an earlier version of Visual Studio again.

Comment: Where is this backup stored?

Comment: It should create a folder named *Backup* inside your existing solution folder. I presume you are asking about a more recent version upgrade, so checking [Project migration and upgrade reference for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2022) might be a good idea.